# How to calculate average volume from range of current bar to last 50 bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Is it possible to write shorter code for `calc_avg_volume = math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], ... volume[50])` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ta.sma()` for that.

```
avg = ta.sma(vol, 50)
```